# How to run auto-repeating macro with PlayMacro()?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

The current script I am using is-

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        PlayMacro("macro")
    end
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 4 then
        AbortMacro()
    end
end
```

The macro sequence being-

```
>press LMB
>wait 1400ms
>release LMB
>wait 250ms
```

While its working and aborting as I expected I cannot figure out a way to make it repeat while button 4 is pressed AND at the same time abort mid-sequence if button 4 is released. Any help?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you want (starts repeating on MB#4 press and aborts mid-sequence on MB#4 release).   What problems do you have with the code?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The code I posted above doesn't repeat, it only aborts when MB#4 is released mid sequence. I need to the macro to keep repeating and abort when MB#4 is released.

Comment: I have tried setting repeat while pressed in LGS but it doesn't seem to work with the script

Comment: `I have tried setting repeat while pressed in LGS` - "While pressed" option does not work with `PlayMacro()`.  You should select "Toggle".